# No sound: main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, 19.04, soundcard

I'm not able to use `pulseaudio` so no sound at all in Ubuntu 19.04 and my laptop is Lambda Tensorbook. Anyone could help me to fix this "headache"? Thanks at advance.

```
x@x:~$ pulseaudio -vvv
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 12.0-378-g02fc89
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS:  -g -O0 -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 5.0.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 09:32:09 UTC 2019
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 12 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running from build tree: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: All asserts enabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is a780a212b2e84b5f8f2f3abe253cfbbb.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 2.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/x/.pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/local/lib/pulse-12.0/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.

x@x:~$ ps -ef | grep pulse
x         2089  1604  0 6月30 ?       00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
x         2318  2089  0 6月30 ?       00:00:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulse/gsettings-helper
x        31671 31664  0 09:11 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulse

x@x:~$ snap list
Name  Version    Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core  16-2.39.2  7169  stable    canonical✓  core
vlc   3.0.7      1049  stable    videolan✓   -
```

Comment: `ps -ef | grep pulse` and `snap list` please

Comment: I have updated the output of your command. Please check.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this problem? it's been 5 days i can't fix it

Comment: @HabibRehman I remeber I‘ve sent an email to `Lambda Labs, Inc.`, and the client service sent me a command: `echo "options snd_hda_intel probe_mask=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/tensorbook.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` then reboot, I remeber it worked out (not sure for your case it will works out or not, hope it helps). However, I reinstall another system named `pop_os` later.

Comment: @ahbon, thanks i'll check this out

Answer (score 10):

If you have updated pulseaudio recently or restored old home directory or configuration files, you could try:

```
rm  ~/.config/pulse/*
```

This should remove your current defaults for pulseaudio which are apparently not working.

After this, please reboot your system to build new pulseaudio configuration files.

Comment: Thank you very much. I remove `x@x:~/.pulse$ locate default-sink
/home/x/.config/pulse/a780a212b2e84b5f8f2f3abe253cfbbb-default-sink
/home/x/.pulse/a780a212b2e84b5f8f2f3abe253cfbbb-default-sink`, then should I reboot?

Comment: Yes, please reboot

Comment: OK, I try with that and let you know what happens. BTW, just wonder why there two `.pulse` path for `*default-sink`, it's confusing, should I remove one?

Comment: better to remove all files in that directory and reboot. They will be rebuilt after reboot. run    `rm  ~/.config/pulse/*`  and reboot

Comment: In your case. Please delete all the files in `/home/x/.config/pulse/` only.

Comment: fixed it for me.
Just deleting the files and then a restart did it.

Comment: For me as Raffa I did as said above, but I had to reboot it fast, dunno why maybe for some reason it was creating the files before I reboot it
So rm ~/.config/pulse/* && reboot Did it for me

Answer (score -1):

> I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/local/lib/pulse-12.0/modules.

It seems you compiled something related to  pulseaudio on your own.
comment in the files under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` the entries that points to `/usr/local/lib/` out. With `sudo ldconfig -v` update/create the links and cache for your libraries new.

Comment: `x@x:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ ls
cuda-10-1.conf  fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf  i386-linux-gnu.conf  libc.conf  x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`