# My internal mic is not working on a Lenovo Ideapad 330

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, lenovo, microphone

I've recently starting using Ubuntu 20.04 and everything is working fine but my internal mic. The system seems to recognize it but it's making low sizzling sound.

I've already tried this command `rm  ~/.config/pulse/*` and reboot and the system but it didn't work.

The system shows this error:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Comment: Here is the best solution I found. **TiVP**'s last answer is the one that has images that guide you what to do. [https://github.com/pop-os/pipewire/issues/8](https://github.com/pop-os/pipewire/issues/8)

Comment: I recommend that once fixed, you do not modify the volume with POP! OS. If you do, you will have to reboot or run the command `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore`. Just modify it with QasMixer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound: main.c: pa\_pid\_file\_create() failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155038/no-sound-main-c-pa-pid-file-create-failed)