# Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 9 Internal Microphone not appearing

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, thinkpad, microphone

I don't recall having this issue before, as I've been able to use Zoom on my laptop with internal microphone. I haven't done so often though, so can't pinpoint which update may have broken my internal microphone.

I have always used Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and it's been great. However when I go into the sound settings and lookup my input devices, the device if I recall correctly, "Digital Microphone" is no longer present. All I see is "Analog input - built in audio" which is my 3.5mm socket on the laptop.

As I needed to fix an unrelated annoyance, I felt it was time to format/reinstall. I installed 22.04.3 LTS and still face the same problem on a fresh install. Now I'm *really* unsure what has borked the audio. Output is still ok though. See my lspci below;

```
brad@thinkpadx1:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 01)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 01)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
```

Has anyone else had this issue with this particular laptop? I've notice similar issues on previous ubuntu versions, and previous gen thinkpad X1s, but I've not had this issue prior. I'm at a loss to what it could be.

EDIT: There's also an audio output issue. I hadn't noticed i much as I've had the laptop on a dock and use the dock's audio/stereo system for sound. When not docked, the internal speakers only have one volume: max. No mantter how many steps up or down you've turned the system volume, it stays maximum, unless you turn it to 0, whereby it's muted.

This was *NEVER* an issue. To find that issues are with the audio, and persisting through nuke/reinstall, I suspect maybe a bad firmware update? That's literally the only change persisting on my system since the time it worked OK.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix that worked for me (found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1155043)

1. Remove current defaults for pulseaudio

   ```
   rm  ~/.config/pulse/*
   ```
2. Then reboot to build new pulseaudio configuration files

I had the same problem:

- lost sound from my laptop when using a docking station
- but sound worked well with the docking station unplugged

I have

- Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9
- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

The problem appeared for me today:

- it worked fine in AM
- without specific updates, I lost sound with docking station in PM

I don't know why pulseaudio's defaults started to malfunction.

(Also, maybe your fresh install didn't work because you've copied your home on your new install with pulseaudio defaults malfunctioning from your previous install.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that doesn't seem to have fixed my problem. 

One difference with my problem is that audio works great with my dock. It's just the internal laptop speakers, they only have one volume step, maximum, even if it's turned down to the minimum level. 

And the problem still occurs even after nuking the system and reinstalling ubuntu 22.04