# No Sound Issue: "Dummy Output" on Ubuntu 22.04 with Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

** No Sound Issue: "Dummy Output" on Ubuntu 22.04 with Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio **

**Description:**
I'm encountering a sound issue on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, and I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot it. Currently, I have "Dummy Output" as the only available sound output device.

**System Information:**

- **OS:** Ubuntu 22.04
- **Kernel:** Linux Swift 6.2.0-33-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
- **Audio Controller:** Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

```
 % sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-dummy snd-hrtimer snd-sof-pci-intel-skl snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof-pci snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-sof snd-sof-utils snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-avs snd-soc-hda-codec snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-intel-sdw-acpi snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hrtimer snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-dummy snd-hrtimer snd-sof-pci-intel-skl snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof-pci snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-sof snd-sof-utils snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-avs snd-soc-hda-codec snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-intel-sdw-acpi snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.  

                                                                                                                                   
~ % grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2


~ % lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 Audio                                                                                                                                                                                  
37:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)                                                                                                      
38:     Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1025:1245]                                                                                                                                     
39-     Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_soc_avs, snd_sof_pci_intel_skl                                                                                                                               
40-00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)                                                                                                                               
41-     Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [1025:1245]                                                                                                                                        
42-     Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus 

                                                                                                     
~ % aplay -l                                                                                                                                                                                                         
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...




% dpkg -L linux-modules-$(uname -r) | grep snd                                                                                                                                                                     
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko                                                                                                                                                 
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko                                                                                                                                             
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko                                                                                                                                            
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko                                                                                                                                                  
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko                                                                                                                                               
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko                                                                                                                                                       
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko                                                                                                                                                      
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-ctl-led.ko                                                                                                                                                       
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko                                                                                                                                                       
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko                                                                                                                                                         
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko                                                                                                                                                 
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-seq-device.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-ens1370.ko 


~ % cat /proc/asound/cards                                                                                                                                                                                           
--- no soundcards --- 

~ % modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko                                                                                                                                                       
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }                                               
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko                                                                                                                                                  
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }                                                                                        
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko                                                                                                                                                  
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko                                                                                                                                                
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko                                                                                                                                           
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-sdw-acpi.ko                                                                                                                                          
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko                                                                                                                                            
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko   

~ % pulseaudio -vvv                                                                                                                                                                                                  
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted                                                                                                                             
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted                                                                                                                             
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.                                                                                                                                                         
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.                                                                                                                                                                     
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.                                                                                                                                                     
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 15.99.1                                                                                                                                                                   
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: Not yet supported on meson                                                                                                                                               
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 6.2.0-33-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 10:33:52 UTC 2                                                                              
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.                                                                                                                                                                                
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes                                                                                                                                                                      
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no                                                                                                                                                           
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no                                                                                                                                                                 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no                                                                                                                                                                            
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running from build tree: no                                                                                                                                                                  
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes                                                                                                                                                                         
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: All asserts enabled.                                                                                                                                                                         
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is c17f95c5e5cf40c580d027a5d2fe9e1d.                                                                                                                                              
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.                                                                                                                                                
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/sasha/.config/pulse.                                                                                                                                             
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-15.99.1+dfsg1/modules.                                                                                                                                
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no                                                                                                                                                                   
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.                                                                                                                                                                       
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed. 

~ % sudo dmesg | grep -iE 'snd|sound|alsa'                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[    8.975744] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100                                                                                                                
[    8.975759] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SST driver                                                                                                                 
[    9.362640] snd_soc_avs 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100                                                                                                                  
[    9.362656] snd_soc_avs 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SST driver   

~ % cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf                                                                                                                                                                               
# autoloader aliases                                                                                                                                                                                                 
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0                                                                                                                                                                       
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1                                                                                                                                                                       
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2                                                                                                                                                                       
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3                                                                                                                                                                       
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4                                                                                                                                                                       
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5                                                                                                                                                                       
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6                                                                                                                                                                       
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules                                                                                                                                                          
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }                                           
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)                                                                                                                                                      
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }                                                                                
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }                                                                          
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }                          
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }                                                                       
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules                                                                                                                                                
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }                                                                      
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)                                                                                                                                          
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }                                                                               
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0                                                                                                                                                                     
options bt87x index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                               
options cx88_alsa index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                           
options saa7134-alsa index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                        
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                    
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                       
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                   
options snd-usb-audio index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                       
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                       
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                       
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                      
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                       
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci                                                                                                                                                                           
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388                                                                                                                                                                      
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard                                                                                                                                                                 
options snd-pcsp index=-2                                                                                                                                                                                            
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard                                                                                                                                                           
options snd-usb-audio index=-2 



~ % alsamixer                                                                                                                                                                                                        
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'                                                                                                                                                            
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function                                                                                                        
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory   

~ % journalctl -p err                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Sep 18 19:43:40 Sasha-Swift kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.UBTC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dsw>                                                                               
Sep 18 19:43:40 Sasha-Swift kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)                                                                                                
Sep 18 19:43:40 Sasha-Swift kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout                                                                                                                                     
Sep 18 19:43:40 Sasha-Swift kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Failed terminating the transaction                                                                                                                      
Sep 18 19:43:40 Sasha-Swift kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus is busy, can't use it!                                                                                                                            
Sep 18 19:43:46 Sasha-Swift kernel: debugfs: File 'DMIC01 Rx' in directory 'dapm' already present!                                                                                                                   
Sep 18 19:43:46 Sasha-Swift kernel: HDMI HDA Codec ehdaudio0D2: hdac_hdmi_present_sense: disconnect for pin:port 5:0                                                                                                 
Sep 18 19:43:46 Sasha-Swift kernel: HDMI HDA Codec ehdaudio0D2: hdac_hdmi_present_sense: disconnect for pin:port 6:0                                                                                                 
Sep 18 19:43:46 Sasha-Swift kernel: HDMI HDA Codec ehdaudio0D2: hdac_hdmi_present_sense: disconnect for pin:port 7:0                                                                                                 
Sep 18 19:44:01 Sasha-Swift kernel: snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: MCPS Budget Violation: 9b050000                                                                                                                        
Sep 18 19:44:01 Sasha-Swift kernel: snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: MCPS Budget Violation: 9b050000                                                                                                                        
Sep 18 19:44:01 Sasha-Swift kernel: snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: MCPS Budget Violation: 9b050000                                                                                                                        
Sep 18 19:44:01 Sasha-Swift kernel: snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: MCPS Budget Violation: 9b050000                                                                                                                        
Sep 18 19:44:01 Sasha-Swift kernel: snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: ASoC: error at soc_dai_trigger on hdmi2: -32                                                                                                           
Sep 18 19:44:01 Sasha-Swift kernel:  HDA DSP HDMI2: ASoC: trigger FE cmd: 1 failed: -32                                                                                                                              
Sep 18 19:44:02 Sasha-Swift kernel: snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: ASoC: error at soc_dai_trigger on hdmi1: -32
```

Tried to reboot, reinstall pulseaudio and alsa, nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you could solve it with :

`sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio` and then
`systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager`

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps outlined here:

[No sound: main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155038/no-sound-main-c-pa-pid-file-create-failed)

Which says: `rm  ~/.config/pulse/*` (or some variant of that if something has changed since 2019) then reboot. Good luck.

P.S. I found this thread by searching AskUbuntu with `[pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.`  Doing this usually finds threads created by people with the same issue.